# How to get all element which is inside certain character using js regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have 1 string in variable **a** which contain array parsing like variable in string format as shown below in example , I want to get all those index which is bounded by **[** and **]**

```js
var a = 'info.name[0][1][5].data[0]',
  collect = [];

a.split(']').reverse().forEach(function(a) {
  if (a.indexOf('[') !== -1) {
    var splits = a.split('[');
    collect.push(splits[splits.length - 1])
  }
})
console.log(collect);
```

my code shown above works fine I know it fails sometime so ,I am looking more better program if possible please help me to solve this problem with regular expression.

```
**Please Dont Use Jquery or any other libs to solve this problem **
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `match` method:

```js
const a = 'info.name[0][1][5].data[0]';
const collect = a.match(/[^[]+?(?=\])/g) || [];
console.log(collect);
```

The regular expression consists of:

- `[^[]+?`: capture one or more characters that are not `[`. The `?` makes that capturing stop as soon as the next condition is satisfied:
- `(?=\])`: require that the next character is a `]`, but don't capture it.

The `g` modifier will ensure that all matches are returned.

`|| []` is added for the case that there are no matches at all. In that case `match` returns `null`. This addition will output an empty array instead of that  `null`, which may be more practical.

NB: I am not sure why you used `reverse`, but if you really need the output array in reversed order, you can of course apply `reverse` to it.

Answer (score 2):

Match `[`, *capture* anything but a `]` using a negative character set (`[^\]]+`), then match `]`. Then, you can extract every captured group, which will contain the substring matched between the `[]`s:

```js
const a = 'info.name[0][1][5].data[0]';
const collect = [];
const re = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
let match;
while (match = re.exec(a)) {
  collect.push(match[1]);
}
collect.reverse();
console.log(collect);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex with match: `/\b\d+\b/g`

It matches digits between any non alphanumeric values such as [ and ].

```js
const a = 'info.name[0][1][5].data[10]';
const result = a.match(/\b\d+\b/g) || [];
console.log(result);
```